# Reading an unfinished gzip file

Tags: c#, bash, cygwin, gzip, streamreader

I am creating a file using a cygwin bash script on remote:

```
(echo $$ > tail.pid; exec tail -f -n+0 --retry FIX.log) | gzip -c >> /faraway/log.gz
```

At the same time, on my local machine, I am reading /faraway/log.gz in c# using:

```
    txtFileReader = new StreamReader(new GZipStream(new FileStream(@"log.gz"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite), CompressionMode.Decompress, true));

    bool isDone = false; // Set to true when "done.txt" file appears to signal log.gz is completed

    while (true)  // Read until finished
    {
            if (!isDone)
            {
                if (txtFileReader.Peek() == -1) // Wait if file is still being transferred
                {

                    while (!File.Exists(@"done.txt"))
                    {

                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    }
                    isDone = true;

                    // Goes wrong here when gzip closes on remote                       

                }
            }

            if ((line = txtFileReader.ReadLine()) == null)
            {
                    return "";    
            }
    }
```

I have indicated the point in the code where I think it goes wrong.

When (Peek() == -1) and gzip is still running (i.e. it is just slow to transfer data) the next ReadLine works correctly, BUT when gzip is closed on remote, my next ReadLine does not return a correct line - it returns a random part of a line.

Later, when I zcat the file, I see the correct lines were infact sent. So it appears that I am losing the "position" in the gzipstream when gzip shuts down.

What happens when Gzip closes? Does it affect anything previously written?

Comment: what does this have to do with `bash`?

Comment: Have you tried to remove GZIP from the equation? Have you tried not using GZIP? Anyway, I think it is a weird method to send logs from a node to another.

Comment: @Jdamian The process is started from a bash script

Comment: @Jdamian It is unusual, but the reason is I need to process the copy of log file BEFORE the the original has stopped updating.

Comment: the problem is in the GZIP process or in YOUR C# code?